# Javascript and PHP using For loop

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, loops, for-loop

I have the following code that will output a line chart as follows :

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

var line1=[['2008-08-12 ',14], ['2008-09-12 ',6.5], ['2008-10-12 ',5.7], ['2008-11-12 ',9], ['2008-12-12 ',8.2]];

 var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
    title:'Daily Sales',
    axes:{
        xaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
        }
    },
    series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
});
</script>
```

The output for the above code is correct, but i want to insert a PHP loop to select data from mysql and place it insde `var line1` as an array

So I created a test code as follows :

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


<?php


    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    for($i=1;$i<6;$i++){

    $newdate = strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
    $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate ); 
?>
    var line1=[['<?php echo $newdate; ?> ',<?php echo $i ?>]];

<?php
    $date = $newdate;
}
?>


  var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
    title:'Daily Sales',
    axes:{
        xaxis:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
        }
    },
    series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
});
</script>
```

This outputs the last value which is **2015-5-16** and **5** all i want is to output all the result from 1 to 5 and having dates incremented by each month 2014-12-16 to 2015-5-16.

I hope this makes sense ! Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're doing this wrong. You don't use PHP to dump text into a Javascript code block directly. That's a sure-fire way of introducing a javascsript syntax error and killing the entire code block.

You build a native PHP structure (array, object, whatever) and then you json_encode() that.

e.g.

```
<?php

$results = get_data_from_db();
$data = array();
while($row = fetch_row_from_result($results)) {
   $data[] = array($row['foo'], $row['bar']);
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var data_from_db = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your PHP-Block for "var line1=[['..." with this:

```
<?php
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $js = "    var line1=[";
    for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {
        $newdate = strtotime ( '+1 month' , strtotime ( $date ) ) ;
        $newdate = date ( 'Y-m-j' , $newdate );
        if($i>1) { $js.= ", "; }
        $js.= "['".$newdate." ',".$i."]";
        $date = $newdate;
    }
    $js.= "];";
    echo $js;
?>
```